# INSERT INTO a table comparing two other tables using Not EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, syntax, sql-insert

I have 3 tables:

- Server_db_relation
- DatabaseList
- DatabaseList_Archive

The goal is to compare table `Server_db_relation` and `DatabaseList` based on the values in column `ServerName` and `DatabaseName`. If the values do not exists in the table `Server_db_relation`, but do exist in `DatabaseList`, then it should insert the entire row from `DatabaseList` into `DataList_Archive` (those two tables are identical in structure).

In addition, if possible ones the row has been inserted to `DatabaseList_Archive` then delete the record from `DatabaseList`.

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseList_Archieve (Column1, Column2...)
    SELECT * 
    FROM DatabaseList
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM DabaseList, Server_db_relation 
                      WHERE DatabaseList.ServerName = Server_db_relation.ServerName 
                        AND DatabaseList.DatabaseName = Server_db_relatio.[Database])
```

I do not get any syntax errors but no rows are affected. I have added 2 test rows that I know exist in `DatabaseList` and not in `Server_db_relation`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Thanks alot for pointing it out and link. ill change it, in what part of the code does it apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need correlate the sub-query :

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseList_Archieve (Column1, Column2...)
    SELECT dbl.col1, dbl.col2, . .  
    FROM DatabaseList dbl
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                     FROM Server_db_relation sdb 
                     WHERE dbl.ServerName = sdb.ServerName AND 
                           dbl.DatabaseName = sdb.[Database]
                    );
```

Note : I have declared the table alias to make the query easy to ready & write column name or table name (where it comes from).